# Iniciar script depois de um tempo pré-definido

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Eu tô com um probleminha aqui, espero que alguém consiga me ajudar.

Eu tenho dois elementos: `h1` e `h2`, eu fiz um script para efeito de digitação pra ambos, só que eu quero que o efeito de digitação do `h2` seja iniciado somente quando o `h1` for terminado, ou, depois de um tempo que eu selecionar. Tentei fazer dessa forma, mas não deu certo:

```
<script>
                            function typeWrite (elemento) {
                            const textoArray = elemento.innerHTML.split('');
                            elemento.innerHTML = '';
                            textoArray.forEach((letra, i) => {
                             setTimeout(function() {
                                 elemento.innerHTML += letra
                             }, 75 * i)

                            });

                            }
                     const titulo = document.querySelector('h1')
                     typeWrite(titulo);
                     </script>

                     <script>

                        var segundos = 4;

                        setTimeout ( function typeWrite (elemento) {
                        const textoArray = elemento.innerHTML.split('');
                        elemento.innerHTML = '';
                        textoArray.forEach((letra, i) => {
                         setTimeout(function() {
                             elemento.innerHTML += letra
                         }, 75 * i)

                        });

                        }, segundos * 1000);

                 const titulo2 = document.querySelector('h2')
                 typeWrite(titulo2);
                 </script>
```

Alguém pode ma falar qual é o erro? Obrigado!

Comment: Já postei uma sugestão mas aqui vai uma resposta à sua pergunta: o erro é que no `setTimeout` dos 4 segundos você está redeclarando a função `typeWrite` e não chamando ela. O correto seria algo como `setTimeout(()=>{
        const titulo2 = document.querySelector('h2')
        typeWrite(titulo2);
    }, segundos * 1000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só enviar o `h2` para a função `typeWrite` após o tempo que você definiu na variável `segundos`:

```js
function typeWrite (elemento) {
   const textoArray = elemento.innerHTML.split('');
   elemento.innerHTML = '';
   textoArray.forEach((letra, i) => {
      setTimeout(function() {
         elemento.innerHTML += letra
      }, 75 * i)
      
   });
}

const titulo = document.querySelector('h1')
typeWrite(titulo);

var segundos = 4;﻿

setTimeout ( function(){
   const titulo2 = document.querySelector('h2')
   typeWrite(titulo2);
}, segundos * 1000);
```

```html
<h1>texto 1</h1>
<h2>texto 2</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pode enviar a segunda como callback, para que uma espere a outra

Eu mudei a estrutura para utilizar await de promisses ao invés de timeOut, acho que assim fica mais fácil de controlar.

```
<h1>Aqui alguma coisa</h1>
<h2>Aqui outra coisa</h2>
<h3>Esse começa depois de 4 segundos</h3>

<script>
    async function typeWrite(elemento, callback = null) {
        const textoArray = elemento.innerHTML.split('');
        elemento.innerHTML = '';
        var i = -1;
        while(textoArray[++i]) {
            await new Promise((res, rej) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    res(elemento.innerHTML += textoArray[i]);
                }, 75);
            });
        };
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    }
    const titulo1 = document.querySelector('h1');
    const titulo2 = document.querySelector('h2');
    const titulo3 = document.querySelector('h3');
    typeWrite(titulo1, () => typeWrite(titulo2));
</script>
```

### Se quiser iniciar alguma depois de determinado tempo, ai sim use o setTimeout

```
const segundos = 5;
setTimeout(()=>typeWrite(titulo3), segundos * 1000);
```